# Using 'scan' to read into a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am using the 'scan' function in R, but I am confused about the syntax of the "what" parameter.  My goal is to read in a csv matrix and have it represented as a matrix in R as well.

When I use the following code, 'scan' creates a list, not a matrix:

```
auto_skims_2000 <- scan(file = "StLouis_2002_Auto_Peak.csv", what = list(OTAZ=0, DTAZ=0, MIN=0), sep = ",")
```

In particular, I am unclear on how the syntax of the 'what' parameter works. Which of these is correct, if any, for reading in a matrix where the first two columns are integers and the third column is numeric?:

```
what = list(integer, integer, numeric)
what = list(integer(0), integer(0), numeric(0))
what = list('integer', 'integer', 'numeric')
what = c('integer', 'integer', 'numeric')
what = list("integer", "integer", "numeric")
what = list(OTAZ = 0, DTAZ = 0, MIN = 0)
```

PS:  I am using 'scan' instead of 'read.table' intentionally because I am working with a very large dataset which runs more slowly and uses too much memory as a data frame.

Comment: Note: for performance, you can also try fread.

Answer (score 0):

'scan' can only produce two types of output, a vector or a list.  If the 'what' parameter is defined as a list, then the output of 'scan' will also be a list:

> **Value**
>
> if what is a list, a list of the same length and same names (as any) as what.
>
> Otherwise, a vector of the type of what.

The type of the parameter 'what' is defined by sample values of the desired atomic type rather than by the name of the atomic type.  For example:

```
test <- scan(file="filename.csv", sep = ",", what = "numeric")
test <- scan(file="filename.csv", sep = ",", what = "numeric")
```

Both produce vectors of type "character".  While

```
test <- scan(file="filename.csv", sep = ",", what = 0)
test <- scan(file="filename.csv", sep = ",", what = numeric(0))
```

both produce vectors of type "numeric".